# PHP check if value (with accent) from form html exist in array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

Why checking if a value exist in array this one for php is good

```
<option value="Citta">Citta</option>
```

```
$rp = array ('Citta');
if (!in_array($_POST['r'], $rp)) {
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?errore');
        exit;
}
```

and this one instead show the error's header and exit ?

```
<option value="Citt&agrave;">Citt&agrave;</option>
```

```
$rp = array ('Citt&agrave;');
if (!in_array($_POST['r'], $rp)) {
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?errore');
        exit;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: use `isset()` to check array is set or not

Comment: i didn't post all code. Anyway of course i use isset.

Comment: Check `var_dump($_POST)` to see what actually gets posted.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `in_array()` actually compares if the `&agrave;` literally is also present in the string, the comparison is done in a case-sensitive manner. Try using UTF-8 encoded strings and compare them, it will work:

```
<option value="Città">Città</option>
<?php
      $rp = array ('Città');
       if (!in_array($_POST['r'], $rp)) {
             header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?errore');
             exit;
       }

?>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "Try using UTF-8 encoded strings"? if i try with the code above doesn't work (the same error's header and exit).

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta statement to your `<head>` area if you code in HTML5

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

... or take this if HTML 4.x

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Then you can modify your code according to @bodi0's answer:

```
<option value="Città">Città</option>
<?php
    $rp = array ('Città');
    if (!in_array($_POST['r'], $rp)) {
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?errore');
        exit;
    }
?>
```